# SQL: table with multiple colums from one table

Tags: sql, database, join, where-clause, qsqlquery

I’ve got table ROOMS with following columns: ROOM_NO, HSTART, HEND, PPL_Q, CHAIR_Q

I'm trying to achieve table with following:

```
HSTART, HEND, 
PPL_Q (WITH WHERE ROOM_NO = 7 CONDITION),
PPL_Q (WITH WHERE ROOM_NO = 12 CONDITION),
PPL_Q (WITH SUM OF WHERE ROOM_NO IN 7,12 CONDITION), 
CHAIR_Q (WITH WHERE ROOM_NO = 7 CONDITION), 
CHAIR_Q (WITH WHERE ROOM_NO = 12 CONDITION), 
CHAIR_Q (WITH SUM OF WHERE ROOM_NO IN 7,12 CONDITION), 
PPL_PER_CHAIR (WITH SUM OF PPL/ SUM OF CHAIR)
```

Table is propagated with data from image. Finally I'm trying to achieve table like second one from image.

I have try plenty of queries but I cant find out how to do it properly. Queries like this:

```
select HSTART, HEND, CHAIR_Q
from ROOMS
where ROOM_NO in (7,12)
```

This returns no data, and I can't move on with any steps to get my goal.

[tables mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syIKx.png)

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired output to start with (not a picture - people generally doesn't care pictures).

Comment: BTW your definition and your picture do not match, check them.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I'll be aware of that in any further contribution in this portal.

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to be mostly static and you could do it like:

```
SELECT
    t1.hstart
  , t1.hend
  , t1.chair_q                                                              AS Chair_QR7
  , t2.chair_q                                                              AS Chair_QR12
  , t1.chair_q+t2.chair_q+t3.chair_q                                        AS Chair_QTotal
  , t1.ppl_q                                                                AS PPL_QR7
  , t2.ppl_q                                                                AS PPL_QR12
  , t1.ppl_q+t2.ppl_q+t3.ppl_q                                              AS PPL_TOTAL
  , (t1.ppl_q+t2.ppl_q+t3.ppl_q)* 100.0 /(t1.chair_q+t2.chair_q+t3.chair_q) AS PPL_PER_CHAIR
FROM(SELECT room_no, hstart, hend, chair_q, ppl_q FROM tableName WHERE room_no=7)            t1
    INNER JOIN(SELECT room_no, hstart, hend, chair_q, ppl_q FROM tableName WHERE room_no=12) t2 ON t2.hstart=t1.hstart
                                                                                            AND t2.hend=t1.hend
    INNER JOIN(SELECT room_no, hstart, hend, chair_q, ppl_q FROM tableName WHERE room_no=14) t3 ON t3.hstart=t1.hstart
                                                                                            AND t3.hend=t1.hend;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6e1f355e62b71d0ef23368d4203e7bbd) here. Though the demo is for SQL server, it would apply to almost any SQL backend.

EDIT: For totals you would simply use SUM(). ie:

[DBFiddle demo with totals](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=facd54a4ce7b5ced58437cfd9e9cead3)

PS: Percentage for total is 98.0% not 98.71%. I don't know how you found that 98.71.

Comment: You was right about data type, it's static. Solution it's working for me, partialy. Still got to count total (sum) from each column at the end of the column - not a problem doing it separetly, but still dont have idea how to fit it into this query.

Comment: @dwembe_xl, for totals you could simply use SUM(). I added the sample anyway in the edit.